# Need help to shorten a regex as much as possible

Tags: regex

I have a bit of a weirdly specific problem.

Given a string that looks like

```
.... // some unimportant info 
--------------------

Sockets: r-r-g-b b-b

--------------------
... // some unimportant info
```

I'm trying to determine whether or not my string possesses at least arbitrary number of "r"s, "g"s, and "b"s that are in a connected group in the "Sockets: " line. "The Sockets:" is followed by 1 to 6 r/g/b, that can either be connected together (by a '-') or not (in that case there'll be a '' between two consecutive letters.)

Example : the string above has 2r, 2r1g1b, 2b, but doesn't have 3r nor does it have 3b (because they aren't connected together).

I currently have a solution that's working pretty well :
`ts:.+(?=(\S*r){X})(?=(\S*g){Y})(\S*b){Z}`, where X, Y, Z are the numbers of r, g, b that I'm matching. I do, however, need to reduce it as much as possible (and everything has to be a single regex) because the searchbar that I'm using it for has limited space.

I had an idea about using ((\w-)*\w) to match every single r-r-g... chain, then applying some regex onto the result to verify that the chain has the right number of r, g, b, but I'm unsure how to exactly do that.

Hence :

1. is there a short way to test whether a single-line string contains at least N of a specific character?
2. Is there a short way to apply this test repeatedly on what I've extracted from the previous capture group?
3. If 1) and 2) aren't feasible, do you see a way for me to reduce the size of my first solution?

Comment: Are there always three `x-y-z` groups on the line?

Comment: No. To be perfectly precise, there is 1 to 6 r/g/b on the sockets: line, and each pair of letters can be be separated by a '-' or by a '<space>'. You wouldn't get `r-r-g-b-r-g r-g-b-g r-r-g-b`, but you might end up with `r-r g-g g-b` for example, or `r-r g g g b`.
Also my regex is gonna be generated, so I don't really care about trying to match 1g0b0r for example, since these can be handled by an alternative regex that just tests that the socket line has a "g" in it and not worry about the groups at all.

Comment: Are there 5 groups here `r-r g g g b`? What differentiates `r-r-g-b-r-g r-g-b-g r-r-g-b` from your original example `r-r-g-b-r-g r-g-b-g r-r-g-b`, why couldn't you get that one?

Comment: Yeah, r-r g g g b has 5 groups, but see previous edit (dunno if you caught it or not), matching strings that have at least 1g is trivial and can just be done through another simpler regex. The only groups I'm interested in are gonna be the groups with at least 2 linked characters. 

And the original example was just here to give more examples of the types of string I could encounter -- don't think it matters very much that the total # of r/g/b is limited to six in that case? I'll edit the post just in case to remove confusion though.

Comment: This question could use a full description of the language for the `r-g-b` strings, including all conditions. For example, it seems like the letters occur in a specific order, and don't mingle; that is, it's all the `r`, followed by all the `g`, then all the `b`.

Comment: Do you need each space-separated group to be a separate result group, or match the entire 'r-g-b' expression as a single group?

Comment: The r-g-b strings don't have any special conditions sadly. It's 1-6 letters, in any order, with 0-5 connectors between each adjacent pair of letters, that can be either on or of. 

And I don't really care what I match, simply that there is a match at all. 
(to give more info, this regex is used in a game called path of exile, where you can search through your stash of items. Items are each dumped in a string format then parsed through a regex, if the regex returns a match, then the item is highlighted. Here I'm trying to get items that have connected colors of a player's specifications.

Comment: @ZealIskander is regex your only means of doing the search?

Comment: So 'r--g-b   bg  - r' is a valid string? In that case, is the language simply `/[rgb]([- ]{0,5}[rgb]){0,5}/`? Note that ultimately clarifications should be edited into the question itself. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: Another clarification: is each 'r-g-b' string always preceded by "Sockets: ", or might it appear in other contexts? If the latter, what are the rules for the contexts? As it's currently written, it reads like "Sockets: " always precedes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're anyways generating these with a script, you could test each letter in each group individually. You do not need to know beforehand whether the line actually has 1 or 6 groups, but you'd just assume that it can have 6 every time.

So you'd first test for `X`, `Y`, and `Z` in group that has 5 other groups on its right (this only exists if there were 6 groups in total):

```
ts: (\S*r){X}(?=(.* ){5})
ts: (\S*g){Y}(?=(.* ){5})
ts: (\S*b){Z}(?=(.* ){5})
```

Then you'd test  `X`, `Y`, and `Z` in group that has 4 other groups on its right (could be the second group if there happened to be 6 groups in total, or the first group if there were 5 groups in total, does not exist at all if we have 4 or fewer groups in total):

```
ts: (\S*r){X}(?=(.* ){4})
ts: (\S*g){Y}(?=(.* ){4})
ts: (\S*b){Z}(?=(.* ){4})
```

and then just repeat this:

```
ts: (\S*r){X}(?=(.* ){3})
ts: (\S*g){Y}(?=(.* ){3})
ts: (\S*b){Z}(?=(.* ){3})
```

```
ts: (\S*r){X}(?=(.* ){2})
ts: (\S*g){Y}(?=(.* ){2})
ts: (\S*b){Z}(?=(.* ){2})
```

```
ts: (\S*r){X}(?=(.* ){1})
ts: (\S*g){Y}(?=(.* ){2})
ts: (\S*b){Z}(?=(.* ){1})
```

until you get to the final, rightmost group, which always exists:

```
ts: (\S*r){X}(?=(.* ){0})
ts: (\S*g){Y}(?=(.* ){0})
ts: (\S*b){Z}(?=(.* ){0})
```

Comment: This doesn't really help me. It's not a single regex. And it's much longer than my solution, either way.

Comment: No, it's not a single regex, but each piece is shorter than your original one and they can be ran sequentially to gather the full information piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are weak when it comes to counting. They can count a single independent sequence all right (including some simple arithmetic properties, such as even or odd lengths), but if the lengths of two different parts are interdependent, regular expressions become anything from unwieldy to impossible (which happens when maximal length is unbounded). The classic example is strings of the form `aⁿbⁿ` (where `ⁿ` means repeated `n` times) for all integers `n`, which can't be handled by regular expressions. This is due to a fundamental limitation of regular languages, and is behind such laws as the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). They can handle bounded lengths (any finite language is regular; for example `aⁿbⁿ` where `0 ≤ n < 10¹⁰⁰`), but in the general case this involves alternation, which is why it becomes unwieldy.

It should be noted that regexes are distinct from regular expressions; they are programmatic implementations of regular expressions and can be broader in the languages they specify, but they still generally suffer from the same limitations. The one feature that actually expands the language category is [recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), though not every regex library supports them, nor do they help in every case. They can, for example, solve `aⁿbⁿ` (construction left as an exercise), but not `aⁿbⁿcⁿ` (proof left as an exercise).

Since the language in question is bounded, it technically can be matched exactly to a regex by the unwieldy method of listing alternatives (as previously mentioned). This would be messier than a non-regex solution, so isn't much worth considering.

If the regex doesn't need to validate every defining property of the language, then it can be more permissive, matching more than the language. By ignoring some properties, you can create a simple regular language that includes the (possibly non-regular) target language.

In particular, if the regex doesn't need to enforce the 'r-g-b' order, a simple regex can check just the letters and the length: `Sockets: ([rgb](?:[- ][rgb]){0,5})$`. The prefix and suffix expressions can be changed if the pattern is to match in other contexts.

Comment: Nice rambling :D but this doesn't allow counting the occurances or the individual letters.

Comment: @ruohola: as the "rambling" states, those aren't tasks that regexes are suited for, nor is it clear from the question that those are required.

Comment: (Which is exactly the purpose of the "rambling" section: it outlines why the [sought-after solution may be the wrong approach](https://xyproblem.info/).)